# Can $\gamma^5$ matrices be ignored in $q\bar{q}\to ZZ$ processes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, dirac-matrices, regularization, electroweak

In the $q\bar{q}\to ZZ$ process, the following Feynman diagram in LO appears:

[image]

This means for each vertex, the Feynman amplitude contains a term proportional to $(g_V-g_A\gamma^5)$, which makes $D$-dimensional calculations of traces very difficult. In the paper where the figure above is from (doi:10.1016/0550-3213(91)90475-d), the author mentions the following reasoning in order to deal with $\gamma^5$ matrices:

[image]

There are many other papers (like doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.43.3626), where they similarly discard the terms with traces containing $\gamma^5$ in them, however, I do not understand the reasoning behind it. The quoted text above mentions something about these terms having to equal to zero,...

1. ... since we are dealing with two identical vector bosons and thus making it symmetric...
2. ... and the term being proportional to the antisymmetric tensor contracted with independent momenta at the same time.
   I would be really thankful, if someone could explain these conditions in a little bit more detail, and why exactly the discarding of such terms with traces containing $\gamma^5$ matrices justifiable.

An additional, but a little unrelated question: Can this strategy somehow replicated using the HMBV scheme? (i.e. calculating the corresponding traces in $D$ dimensions, and then discarding the terms proportional to the Levi-Civita tensor contracted with the $4-D$ dimensional parts of the momentum)